# Flink checkpoints retained

Tags: java, docker, apache-flink, flink-checkpoint

I have deployed task manager and jobmanager in docker container and configured following in flink-conf.yaml.

```
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///tmp/flink/checkpoints
state.storage.fs.memory-threshold: 0
state.backend.type: rocksdb
state.backend.incremental: true
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 100
```

when i checked the tmp/flink/checkpoints directory of task manager it has lot of chk-X directories though i have configured only 100 to be there.
But in jobmanager tmp/flink/checkpoints directory has only one chk-X(latest check point directory).

Then what is the use of

> state.checkpoints.num-retained

Is it not working in my case? if so what am i missing?.

Or is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: By default, Flink retains 1 completed checkpoint, so if you need a higher number. So you may set it using the same.

Comment: By default, Flink retains 1 completed checkpoint -- where does it happen? in Jobmanger or Taskmanager?

Comment: Added in answer for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

**1) Modify **flink-conf.yaml** file**

Locate the **flink-conf.yaml** file in your Flink installation directory.

Open the **flink-conf.yaml** file in a text editor.

Search for the following configuration property:

```
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 1
```

Change the value to the desired number of retained checkpoints. For example:

```
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 3
```

Save the changes to the file.

**2) Specify Configuration in Job Submission**

Alternatively, you can set the configuration option when submitting your Flink job using the -D command-line option:

```
>./bin/flink run -Dstate.checkpoints.num-retained=3 your-flink-job.jar
```

Replace your-flink-job.jar with the actual JAR file of your Flink job.

After making the changes, Flink will retain the specified number of completed checkpoints for your job. Adjust the value based on your requirements and the resources available in your environment. Keep in mind that retaining more checkpoints can consume additional storage space.